# Computing limit of $ n^k \left ( 1 - \left ( \frac{c \log n}{n} \right )^k \right )^{n^k} $

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I am trying to analyze the asymptotic behavior of
$$
n^k \left ( 1 - \left ( \frac{c \log n}{n} \right )^k \right )^{n^k}
$$
for $c > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Using $(1-x)^n \leq \exp(-x)^n$ for $x \in (0,1)$, I have that
$$
n^k \left ( 1 - \left ( \frac{c \log n}{n} \right )^k \right )^{n^k} \leq n^k \left ( \exp \left ( - \left ( \frac{c \log n}{n} \right )^k\right ) \right )^{n^k} = n^k \exp \left ( c^k \log^k n\right )
$$
which, in particular, for $k = 1$ works out nicely to
$$
n^{1-c} =
\begin{cases}
    \infty & c < 1\\
    1      & c = 1\\
    0      & c > 1
\end{cases},
$$
at least as an upper bound.

In particular, I am interested in the case $k = 2$.

Comment: Have you tried $e^x-1 \sim x, x \to 0$?

Comment: I haven't actually, I'm not certain how that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try and show that as $n$ gets sufficiently large, $c\log(n) < n$ for any $c > 0$ and so $$a = 1-\left(\frac{c\log(n)}{n}\right)^k < 1$$
and now notice that the expression you are interested in is of the form $ta^t$ with $a < 1$. Now show that $a^t$ goes to $0$ faster than $t$ goes to $\infty$ to finally get that $ta^t$ asymptotically approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $f^g=e^{g\ln f}\sim e^{g(f-1)}$, when $f\to 1$ in appropriate assumptions, as $k \in \mathbb{N},c>0$, we have
$$n^k \left ( 1 - \left ( \frac{c \log n}{n} \right )^k \right )^{n^k} = n^k \cdot e^{n^k \cdot \left(-\left ( \frac{c \log n}{n} \right )^k\right)}\to0,n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$y_k=n^k \left ( 1 - x^k \right )^{n^k}\qquad \text{where}\qquad x=\frac{c \log n}{n} $$
$$z=\frac {y_k} {n^k}=\left ( 1 - x^k \right )^{n^k}\implies \log(z)=n^k \log\left ( 1 - x^k \right )$$

Using the usual expansions,
$$\log(z)=-(c \log (n))^k \Bigg[1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac 1 m  \left(\frac{c \log (n)}{n}\right)^{mk}\Bigg]\sim -(c \log (n))^k$$ which makes
$$y_k\sim n^k \exp\left(-(c \log (n))^k\right)$$ already written by @zkutch.

Now, working the asymptotics

$$\log(y_2)=2\log (n) -c^2 \log^2 (n)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log(y_3)=3 \log (n)-c^3 \log ^3(n)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log(y_4)=4 \log (n)-c^4 \log ^4(n)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Guess what will be the next.